# How to Output multiple text files based on column name?

Tags: vba, excel, text, spreadsheet

I have an excel spreadsheet with the following format.

[Excel File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyA5p.jpg)

> column 1: AAA BBB AAA BBB DDD BBB CCC BBB CCC
>
> column 2: Fox Tiger Monkey  Bird  Cat  Wolf  Dog  Fish Pig

I want to save them to multiple text files using column 1 as the file name ---- "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD". The content should be column 2. Each text file should have multiple rows.

For example, in text file "AAA", the content should be:

Fox
Monkey

I am now using the following VBA script. But for each text file, I can only generate one row.

```
Sub Export_Files()
Dim sExportFolder, sFN
Dim rArticleName As Range
Dim rDisclaimer As Range
Dim oSh As Worksheet
Dim oFS As Object
Dim oTxt As Object

'sExportFolder = path to the folder you want to export to
'oSh = The sheet where your data is stored
sExportFolder = "I:\Projects\2017\Two_Weeks_Vacations\2017\December\Test\EmployeesOnVacation"
Set oSh = Sheet1

Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

For Each rArticleName In oSh.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
    Set rDisclaimer = rArticleName.Offset(, 1)

    'Add .txt to the article name as a file name
    sFN = rArticleName.Value & ".txt"
    Set oTxt = oFS.OpenTextFile(sExportFolder & "\" & sFN, 2, True)
    oTxt.Write rDisclaimer.Value
    oTxt.Close
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you able to sort the columns, such that AAA, BBB, AAA, becomes AAA, AAA, BBB?  If so, you can do a quick loop through each cell, otherwise it gets a little more complicated.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I can sort the data, but not sure how to add the loop to the script.

Answer (score 0):

If you can sort, then you can use a base template:

```
Public a as String
```

---

```
Sub 
    Dim i as Long, lr as Long, strO as String, strN as String
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = i to lr Step 1
        strO = a
        If Cells(i,1).Value = Cells(i-1,1).Value Then
            If a <> "" Then Export_Files 'Calls the Sub that names the file... or you can just name and do that stuff here.
            a = ""
            strO = Cells(i,2).Value
        Else
            strN = Cells(i,2).Value
        End If
        a = strO & " " & strN
    Next i
    Export_Files
    a = ""
End Sub
```

Then need to make a fix to the naming of the Export_Files macro, where you remove the parts that pick the file name and change the total file save name:

```
Set oTxt = oFS.OpenTextFile(sExportFolder & "\" & a, 2, True)
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to my question. I will try!